# How to insert a value to the back end table through the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If the data is inserted into the back end table through the gridview , it displays the inserted data, after the insertion is completed. But i do not want to display the inserted data on the gridview, i want to only insert the data and nothing else.

Comment: make sure that your code do not bind gridview after insert record..

Comment: @sangramparmar Now it does not display the inserted record, but it generates a empty row on the gridview for each inserted record. How to avoid this sir.

Comment: Is the table is SQL? if it is one thing you could do (although this is a bit of work) is use Select ScopeIdentity() after each insert to get the ID of the row inserted and then store this in a Hidden field (use "," to separate them all) then when binding your gridview simply change your datasource so that it does not include the split values of the hidden field